# Repeat regex pattern without storing it

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex pattern: `[A-Ba-b0-9\-]\.`

I want to repeat this pattern, so I wrap it in parens: `$repeatingPattern = '([A-Ba-b0-9\-]\.)*';`

I have another regex pattern that I want to capture, so I wrap it in parens too: `$capturePattern = '(stuff)';`

The problem is that I only want to capture `$capturePattern` and not `$repeatingPattern`:

```
preg_match('/' . $repeatingPattern . $capturePattern . '/', $string, $matches)
```

In other words, I would prefer it if `$repeatingPattern` didn't affect what is stored in `$matches`. Is this possible? The only way I know to repeat a regex pattern is with parens, which are also used for capturing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use non-capturing group in your first regex:

```
$repeatingPattern = '(?:[A-Ba-b0-9\-]\.)*';
```

Syntax for `non-capturing group` is `(?:...)` which groups but doesn't capture.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [non-capturing group: `(?:` ... `)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php).

Answer (score 0):

Or lookbehind: `(?<=[A-Ba-b0-9\-]\.)`. This ensures `$repeatingPattern` is found just before your `$capturePattern`.

Comment: This assumes that OP requires a `$repeatingPattern` before `$capturePattern`. Given that the `$repeatingPattern` is quantified with a `*`, that would mean there could be zero or more and is not required.